What is the difference between double asterisks and single asterisk in a comment in java (Or IntelliJ)?
As the attached images show, if I put two asterisks after the slash in a comment, the comment will be rendered in green. If there's only one, the comment would be rendered in grey. I bet this is a feature of the editor IntelliJ, but I wonder what this is used for?


https://www.oracle.com/de/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html#writingdoccomments

Also note that in Java 23, comments prefixed with /// will be different from //. The former will be for documentation comments using Markdown format.

The difference is, that block comments that start with a double "**" are able to be interpreted and included in the automatic generation of a javadoc-documentation and also often used to differentiate between temporary and permanent comments used for documentation.
Block comments that start with only one "*" are simply regular block comments. If you want to read more about javadoc and javadoc-comments i would advise you to read this
Javadoc is not exclusive to any specific IDE, so you can use this method of documentation in any java programming environment.

Double asterisk comments are for documentations, as they are used to generate external documentation about your source code. On the other hand single asterisk comments are simply for multi line comments (To avoid using "//" on every line)
.
